# Enable Bitlocker only for the user account/folder

Tags: windows, windows-10, encryption, bitlocker, veracrypt

I use BitLocker to encrypt my system drive + a couple more, it works great but comes with a major annoyance: I remote in to my computer a lot and my area suffers from power outages whenever it rains which then locks my computer to a pre-boot BitLocker password prompt so I can't enter anymore without getting back home first.

Is there any way I could have BL unlock just my user account after I log in while the rest of the drive "runs" unencrypted?

(yeah I know about UPS)

Comment: BitLocker is Full Disk Encryption, you cannot use BitLocker, to encrypt a single folder.  What you want is not possible.  If you want to encrypt a single folder use EFS (Encrypted File System) instead.  There is no way to do what you have asked.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple solution. Divide your disk in two partitions. On partition 1 (probably the C drive) you install Windows without Bitlocker. It boots without issues, you can login. You encrypt the second partition (D for data?) with Bitlocker, and use that for you documents.

I don't know if you can put your complete user account on that drive, or use that complete D-partition for your user account. I have no idea how to configure that, don't use Windows myself. But you could create another user account on the C drive, just to login, then unlock D, and login to your normal account.

Another option is to encrypt a folder: [How to Encrypt Individual Files and Folders in Windows 10](https://www.groovypost.com/howto/encrypt-individual-files-folders-windows-10/)

Comment: That would be incredibly inconvenient (space) and problematic to setup (symlinks to AppData etc)

Comment: @hikari: BitLocker works at whole partition level, so this is unavoidable.

Comment: You can use Veracrypt or see my updated answer. What you want is inconvenient. Power outages are inconvenient. The question is: what is more inconvenient? If there is no better solution, the solution is either difficult or messy. Make you choice unless somebody else comes up with a better solution.